# Selenium chromedriver goog:chromeOptions in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

Baed on https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/issues/201 I see that in recent versions of selenium there is a new option 'goog:chromeOptions' . Does this apply to python . If so how do I pass in 'goog:chromeOptions' as an argument , as you can see in the screenshot is causes a syntax error.

Comment: I had to recently update a ruby stack with this new `goog:chromeOptions`.  And I found it from some python related thread so I think it applies in many cases now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [official doc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver), it doesn't seem change in Python.

Or maybe I misunderstand what you want to do? [Here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/commit/3578c0faee107dc0faef164a4acf02b916caa2be#diff-10f65ccee5b377aa8f2b3fde4bf566f8L169) is a related commit. It shows that the key in `capabilities` has been changed. But I think you don't need to directly interact with it?